# Cambiar link blob a un link base64

Tags: javascript

Qué puedo hacer para que el link no sea un blob si no un base64 teniendo en cuenta que esto será automáticamente sin usar el **input type file**.

```js
mediaRecorder.onstop = function(e) {
      audio.controls = true;
      var blob = new Blob(chunks, {
        'type': 'audio/ogg; codecs=opus'
      });
      
      chunks = [];
      audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    }

    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
      chunks.push(e.data);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para la primera pregunta sobre que quieres convertir el `blob` a `base64` en realidad es muy sencillo, pero para la segunda, no puedes transmutar audio tan fácilmente en JavaScript puro, de hecho creo que ni siquiera se puede con las herramientas nativas que brinda JavaScript. Para ello tendrías que usar frameworks que facilitan este propósito y que tengan acceso a la shell, por ejemplo, uno de esos casos es Node.js, así que omitiré la segunda parte, puesto que no es algo corto y merece, creo, una pregunta completa aparte de por sí sola...

Entonces para convertir un audio de tipo blob a base64, basta con simplemente leerlo por medio de `FileReader` como tal pasándole el blob que tienes de referencia así:

```js
const inputFile = document.getElementById("inputFile");

function readAsBase64(fileBlob){

  return new Promise((res, rej)=>{
  
    const fileReader = new FileReader();
  
    fileReader.onload = ()=>{
      res(fileReader.result);
    }

    fileReader.onerror = e =>{
      rej(e);
    }
    
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileBlob);
    
  });

}

function handleFiles(ev){

  const fileBlob = ev.currentTarget.files[0];
  const base64promise = readAsBase64(fileBlob);
  
  base64promise.then((base64)=>{
    console.log(base64);
  })
  .catch(e =>{
    console.log(e);
  });
}

inputFile.addEventListener("change", handleFiles);
```

```html
<input type = "file" id = "inputFile" accept = "audio/*">
```

Como vemos es muy sencillo, solo debemos hacer uso del método `readAsDataURL` de `FileReader` para leer nuestro archivo como un base64.